# Problema con un margen (Usando bootstrap 4)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Tengo un problema usando  bootstrap, capaz es muy simple pero no encuentro como solucionarlo y es que me deja "un margen blanco" al lado del carrusel y la barra rosada... (O no se si mas bien es que la barra gris tendrá alguna característica que la haga ser mas larga...)

[image: Muestro el margen blanco.]

No se como añadir el código aun, primera vez en esta pagina y me sale de una manera extraña D:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">

    <title>MafeMakeUP</title>

  </head>

  <body>
<!--Barra informativa -->
<div class="row barrainfo">
  <div class="col-md-4 textinfo"> Email: itsmafemakeup@gmail.com </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 textinfo"> Contacto: (VE)+58414-2691128  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 textinfo"> Social: @itsmafemakeup </div>
</div>
<div class="row contenidoheader">
  <div class="col-4 headerlogo"><img class="imglogo" src="img/logo.png"></div>
  <div class="col-8 contenedorheader">
    <div class="row">
<div class="textheader"><a href="inicio" style="color: green; text-decoration: none;">INICIO</a></div>
<div class="textheader"><a href="quiensoy" style="color: green; text-decoration: none;">¿QUIEN SOY?</a></div>
<div class="textheader""><a href="cursosperso" style="color: green; text-decoration: none;">CURSOS PERSONALIZADOS</a></div>
<div class="textheader"><a href="contacto" style="color: green; text-decoration: none;">CONTACTAME</a></div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Fin de barra informativa-->

<!-- Carrusel del INDEX -->
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100 imgcarousel" src="img/maquillaje.jpg" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100 imgcarousel" src="img/maquillaje2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100 imgcarousel" src="img/maquillaje3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
<!-- Fin del carrrusel -->






    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="particles.php"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Y aca esta el CSS**

```
.barrainfo {
  max-height: 140.73px;
  background-color: #DADDDF;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-left: 90px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.textinfo {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.textheader {
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 90px;
  padding-top: 22px;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: red;
}

.imgfondo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.contenedorheader {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.imglogo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.headerlogo {
  height: 65px;
  background-color: aqua;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.contenidoheader {
  height: 65px;
  max-height: 250px;
  background-color: pink;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.imgcarousel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 508px;
}
```

Comment: El código se añade poniendo 4 espacios al comienzo de cada línea. Te recomiendo seleccionar el código y darle los espacios con la tecla de tabulación (Tu editor de texto debe estar configurado a usar espacios en lugar de tabs),

Comment: ¿A cada linea de código le tengo que añadir 4 espacios? Uso Sublime y esta configurado para dar el espaciado con tabs, solamente que yo uso esto en ciertas ocasiones que quiero ordenar mas no en todo el código.

Comment: Pega el código como esta, seleccionalo y apretá `Ctrl + K` y se va a identar automáticamente

Comment: Listo, pero sale de una manera extraña.

Comment: Intenta poner max-width: 100%; al body y a los divs que componen tu carrousel